# Unable to process a cube via a job that calls SSIS on another server

Tags: sql-server, ssas, jobs

We have recently moved an SSAS cube & its database to a different server.  Both are SQL Server 2012 RTM.

We are using an SSIS package to handle processing of the day's partition. (The same package as on the server we restored from) The job exists on the box with the SSAS, but the job STEP points at a SQL Server 2012 box running SSIS.

If we run the SSIS package, it succeeds.  However, if we try to run the package via the agent on the SSAS box, it fails.  That user has been added as a SSAS server admin just in case, but hasn't changed anything.

Also, we set up a job running the SSIS package on the SSIS server. It works.

When the job fails, the SSIS error message: "A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running."

Only message in the server event logs: "Package "Process_Partitions" Failed"

If we run an SSAS profiler trace, we get 3 events: Progress Report Begin, Notification, Progress Report End, all at the same time, but without anything else.

One other thing worth mentioning: we have two instances of SSAS on the server: traditional (the default instance) and tabular.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: What user is the SQL Server Agent running as? Does that user have appropriate permissions on the Analysis Service cube to process? Also, there should be a better error in the job history.

Comment: Found part of the problem - we couldn't get the package to deploy to SSISDB on the server itself, so it's deployed to a different server, and the error message is on the other server.  I'll update.  "A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be a double hop issue (Kerberos Delegation). Essentially, the job passes the SQL Server Agent credentials on [Server with Job] to [Server with Job Step] which then passes the credentials to [Server with Cube].

[Server with Job] - First Hop - [Server with Job Step] - Second Hop - [Server with Cube]

If this is the case and Kerberos Delegation isn't properly configured, the trace on the cube or tabular model should reveal an Anonymous NTUsername.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like Kerberos issues of some sort.  The SSAS traces shows "ANONYMOUS LOGON".  The Microsoft Kerberos Configuration Manager doesn't show any problems with either box, though... hmm...

Comment: It will probably be easier / quicker to get the SSIS package working on the server the Job runs than getting Kerberos Delegation working. Haven't trying the configuration manager yet, but I have successfully configured Kerberos Delegation on Sharepoint. Getting Excel services to double hop to the cube was a nightmare.